# Is this valid Modus Ponens?

Tags: logic

I am taking a course in discrete structures and have just started using rules of inference. One of my homework problems contains the following step:

$$P \vee Q \to S$$

I also know from the problem that P is true, so I can write:

$$P \vee Q \to S$$

$$P$$

Therefore S.

Could I call this Modus Ponens? Or is it something else?

Comment: No, it's not quite Modus Ponens. The first step would be deriving $P\lor Q$ from $P$; now $S$ follows by Modus Ponens from $P\lor Q$ and $P\lor Q\to S$.

Comment: You have to use [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction): $P \to (P\lor Q)$

Comment: Okay, I see now. Thank you both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you skipped Addition. ie. If you are given a true statement P then you can infer P or Q where Q is some other statement. And then you can use Modus Ponens.

Comment: "or" is used in Inclusive sense.

Comment: "or" refers to Disjunction